# Create an array in java where values are sorted randomly

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I randomly fill an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496774/how-do-i-randomly-fill-an-array-in-java)

The last line of code below prints numbers in order. How to create an array where value are sorted randomly?

```
          List<Users> u = new ArrayList<Users>();
          u.add(new Users(1, 5));
          u.add(new Users(2, 4));
          u.add(new Users(3, 8));

          for (Users us1 : u)
          {
            int si1 = us1.getCf();
            int di = us1.getId();
            for (int j = 0; j < si1; j++)
            {
              System.out.println("cf:" + di);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Create a permutation of the indexes using Random and then load the values into the final array using that to set the order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: possiblity of duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2496774/668970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use,

```
Collections.shuffle(yourList)
```

As per your requirement I made some changes in your code,

```
List<Users> u = new ArrayList<Users>();  
u.add(new Users(1, 5));  
u.add(new Users(2, 4));  
u.add(new Users(3, 8));  
Collections.shuffle(u);  

List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
for (Users us1 : u) {  
    int si1 = us1.i;  
    int di = us1.i;  
    for (int j = 0; j < si1; j++) {  
        System.out.println("cf:" + di);  
        output.add(di);  
    }  
}  

Integer[] result = output.toArray(new Integer[output.size()]);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: how to create an array with the data System.out.println("cf:"+di);

Comment: I have edited my answer to create an array...

Comment: Oh! it works... thanks. I only replace the code of shufle to   output: I want the new array to be sorted by random

Comment: Nice to hear that! If you find this answer was correct then you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).